# How to download a .py file from Jupyter lab notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In jupyter notebook, there is a provision to download a notebook as .py file. In jupyter lab, there is an option called export as which does not contain an option to download a .py file. Is there any workaround for this, instead of copying the script in the notebook and pasting it in a python file.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In Jupyter lab, go to File Menu. Select "Export Notebook as" and then choose the "Export Notebook to Executable Script" option.

For Jupyter notebook, there is "Download as" option in File menu of Jupyter notebook. You can select Python (.py) from the list of available options.

Comment: The question is for jupyter lab.

Comment: @TarunKumarYellapu I've updated my answer for exporting in Jupyter lab.

Comment: This will export the `.py` file, removing all the structure (e.g. cells). Is there not a way to download as `.ipynb`?

Comment: "Export Notebook to Executable Script" in my mac saves a .py.html file. No python executable

Comment: You should be able to run the file by removing the `.html` extension. It's a Safari thing.

Comment: While it is an executable script, they hid that one really really well (considering the fact that in Jupyter Notebook (not Lab), it's simply "Download as .py")

Answer (score 2):

From the jupyter docs: (https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/export.html)
JupyterLab allows you to export your jupyter notebook files (.ipynb) into other file formats such as:

```
Asciidoc .asciidoc

HTML .html

Latex .tex

Markdown .md

PDF .pdf

ReStructured Text .rst

Executable Script .py

Reveal.js Slides .html
```

To access these options, while a notebook is open, browse the File menu:

Comment: It would be helpful if they put the .py extension in the menu label.  "Executable Script" feels like a .exe file.